# do an action after a connection lapse time

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, session-variables

Hello everyone it's been a while since I'm looking for the solution to my problem I'm developing a web application and I'm blocking that day.

the objective is that after a time from the beginning of the connection of the user I make a precise action.

I will not give all the code is too long so I will try to be as simple as possible :

my first PHP script 1 validate the user login and create a session variable that takes the current time and then returns the user to the PHP script 2 :

```
 session_start();
 .
 .
 .// some code ....
 if(password_verify($password,$pass_sql))
        {

             $_SESSION['autorisation'] = 'oui';
             $_SESSION['ConnectOK'] = true;

             $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
             $_SESSION['debut'] = time(); // this is the variable of time

            header("Location:http://jawad.meswatts.fr/sous/meswatts.php");
        }
```

meswatts.php :

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 if(  !empty($_SESSION['autorisation']) AND  $_SESSION['autorisation'] =='oui' )        
  {
      $t_navigation = time();
      if($t_navigation - $_SESSION['debut'] >= 12 )
        {
            echo " hello" ; // just exemple of action
        }
     .
     .
     .
     . //the rest of the code is only HTML that is not very important




   }     
?>
```

and so in the second PHP script I still use the time function and I do a subtraction with the session variable that I created in the first page and so there will be an action after 12 seconds unfortunately it does not work not after the passage of 12 seconds nothing happens any help would be helpful !

Comment: "*after the passage of 12 seconds nothing happens*" - that's because you need to refresh the page to execute the PHP code again.

Comment: Or write a loop to keep checking the time difference until it is >= 12

Comment: or you maybe wanna set  a timeout in javascript to do something after 12 (milli?)seconds

Comment: sidenote: if both scripts are on the same server you don't need to set the location to the full url, a relative path (eg 'sous/meswatts.php')  is enough

Comment: thanks guy !! i think i will use java script to chck time ! it's the better way maybe !